# Cant start aptana studio 3

Tags: aptana

version - 3.0.4 on windows 7 64bit

everytime i started it manage to get til splash screen, then it crash. cant remember when this start to happen, prolly after i updated to 3.0.4. this is the log:

> ### !SESSION 2011-09-21 22:44:41.826
>
> eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.6.0_24 java.vendor=Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32,
>   NL=en_MY Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-09-21 22:44:43.676 !MESSAGE An
>   unexpected runtime error has occurred. !STACK 0
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4109)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3969)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TaskBar.createHandle(TaskBar.java:99)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TaskBar.(TaskBar.java:92)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemTaskBar(Display.java:2499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$TaskBarDelegatingProgressMontior.getTaskItem(Workbench.java:300)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$TaskBarDelegatingProgressMontior.handleTaskBarProgressUpdated(Workbench.java:316)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$TaskBarDelegatingProgressMontior.worked(Workbench.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$StartupProgressBundleListener.bundleChanged(Workbench.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:919)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1349)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1300)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.createInstance(ServiceComponent.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.createInstance(ServiceComponentProp.java:264)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.ServiceReg.getService(ServiceReg.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse$1.run(ServiceUse.java:120)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse.getService(ServiceUse.java:118)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:447)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:430)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:667)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.addingService(ServiceTracker.java:442)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:896)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:261)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:184)
>     at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:339)
>     at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:273)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getBundleGroupProviders(InternalPlatform.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundleGroupProviders(Platform.java:1261)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin.getFeatureInfos(IDEWorkbenchPlugin.java:281)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder.makeFeatureDependentActions(WorkbenchActionBuilder.java:1178)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder.makeActions(WorkbenchActionBuilder.java:1001)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.ActionBarAdvisor.fillActionBars(ActionBarAdvisor.java:147)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder.fillActionBars(WorkbenchActionBuilder.java:335)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.fillActionBars(WorkbenchWindow.java:3533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.(WorkbenchWindow.java:414)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.tweaklets.Workbench3xImplementation.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench3xImplementation.java:31)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.newWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1881)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$14(Workbench.java:1879)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$21.runWithException(Workbench.java:1199)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2011-09-21 22:44:43.680 !MESSAGE 
>   !STACK 0 org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4109)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3969)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TaskBar.createHandle(TaskBar.java:99)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TaskBar.(TaskBar.java:92)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemTaskBar(Display.java:2499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$TaskBarDelegatingProgressMontior.getTaskItem(Workbench.java:300)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$TaskBarDelegatingProgressMontior.handleTaskBarProgressUpdated(Workbench.java:316)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$TaskBarDelegatingProgressMontior.worked(Workbench.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$StartupProgressBundleListener.bundleChanged(Workbench.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:919)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1349)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1300)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.createInstance(ServiceComponent.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.createInstance(ServiceComponentProp.java:264)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.ServiceReg.getService(ServiceReg.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse$1.run(ServiceUse.java:120)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse.getService(ServiceUse.java:118)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:447)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:430)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:667)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.addingService(ServiceTracker.java:442)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:896)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:261)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:184)
>     at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:339)
>     at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:273)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getBundleGroupProviders(InternalPlatform.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundleGroupProviders(Platform.java:1261)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin.getFeatureInfos(IDEWorkbenchPlugin.java:281)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder.makeFeatureDependentActions(WorkbenchActionBuilder.java:1178)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder.makeActions(WorkbenchActionBuilder.java:1001)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.ActionBarAdvisor.fillActionBars(ActionBarAdvisor.java:147)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder.fillActionBars(WorkbenchActionBuilder.java:335)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.fillActionBars(WorkbenchWindow.java:3533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.(WorkbenchWindow.java:414)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.tweaklets.Workbench3xImplementation.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench3xImplementation.java:31)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.newWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1881)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$14(Workbench.java:1879)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$21.runWithException(Workbench.java:1199)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-09-21 22:44:43.955 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
>     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4109)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3969)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TaskBar.createHandle(TaskBar.java:99)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TaskBar.(TaskBar.java:92)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemTaskBar(Display.java:2499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createProgressIndicator(WorkbenchWindow.java:3331)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.java:623)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents(WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:268)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1016)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$22.runWithException(Workbench.java:1208)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading and installing:

1. Sun 64-bit JRE
2. [Eclipse Classic for Windows 64-bit](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7-201106131736/index.php)
3. Install [Aptana Studio as a plugin](http://www.aptana.com/downloads/start) into Eclipse Classic.

Cheers,
Max